# Domain name is opening the website but its IP address shows nginx Not found

Tags: ssh, ip, dns-hosting, digital-ocean, winscp

My domain name is www.blissedmaths.com. Its IP is 159.89.162.44.
*while opening through blissedmaths.com, it opens. But IP address not working. Due to that, I am unable to access my droplet via WinSCP (by SSH)*

How can I access my droplet on the digital ocean?

Comment: When you created the droplet, did you add a public key?

Comment: Its seem that your SSH daemon is dead, telnet couldn't establish a connection with the server over port 22. Use the web console to login as root and run `service ssh restart`

Answer (score 0):

That's because SSH is not enabled on your server. SSH uses port number 22 by default to allow connections (unless otherwise changed).

Make sure SSH is installed/running on your server. The package name for SSH may differ depending on your OS (not for windows though).

On a side note, you should turn **Debug = False** in your DJango Settings file to disable showing directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is visible via port 80, and is generally made visible to the world.  SSH, is on port 22, and is usually disallowed for "anyone" to access, unless you explicitly allow it through their firewall.

I suspect you will need to "allow SSH" via the administrative interface at Digital Ocean in order to make it work.